# Make an alias that does an alias command

Tags: shell, alias

I have to make an alias that will do the alias command. It has to "replace" the alias command and the user has to feel no difference..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment yet to your post, so i'll post a suggestion.

Do you just want an alternative command to alias that the user can call?

```
alias alias2=alias
```

Or do you want to replace the alias command with an alias you've written?

```
alias alias=/path/to/executable
```

Can you elaborate?

Comment: I just want an alternative..

Comment: Then `alias myalias=alias` is the way to go

Comment: @polym - you can leave comments now!

Comment: @slm haha cool thx :)